# Update each user status in array firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

I get the user id's which is not contains a specific word. I need to update user status.

```
var primeusers = [];
var komence= firebase.database().ref();

function thisclick() {
    komence.child('Buyers').on("value", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
       if(!data.val().Nealdi.includes("GPA")) {
         primeusers.push(data.key);
       }
    });
    console.log(primeusers);
  });
}
```

I can get the user id's.But I can't update their status.

```
//Update statatus to user under on "Users". 
var vipata = firebase.database().ref();

vipata.child("Users").child(`primeusers`).once('value', function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
      child.ref.update({Minivip: "NO"});
      child.ref.update({VIP: "NO"});
    });
});
```

Database structure.

```
|-Buyers
|--Userid
|---Nealdi

|-Users
|--Userid
|---Minivip
|---VIP
```

Comment: Please share your structure.

Comment: Updated first message.

Comment: Which error do you get ?

Comment: Nothing ! Now i use primeone= primeusers[0]; primetwo= primeusers[1];....

cork1b.child("Users").child(primeone).child("Minivip").set("No");
cork2b.child("Users").child(primeone).child("VIP").set("No");...

So i declared ref for each value.It's work,but it's take a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suppose you forgot the child "primeusers" in the structure schema shown. Try that:

```
var vipata = firebase.database().ref("Users");

vipata.child(`primeusers`).once('value', function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.val().forEach(function(child) {
      child.ref.update({Minivip: "NO"});
      child.ref.update({VIP: "NO"});
    });
});
```

Note here you are doing an update for each child. You can upgrade that by updating your object in your client side, and then update the entire object in once (it will be more beneficial for you). (I can link you an example if you want one).